# Review Queue filter drop-down cut off screen

Tags: bug, design

This bug is little more than a minor nuisance, but it strikes me as something that would be easy to fix and improve user experience if it were changed.

When you set a filter on the review queue, and then you complete all reviews that satisfy that filter, the filter drop-down gets cut off screen because it doesn't fit in the surrounding div.

[image]

A scrollbar appears, but it is on the far right of the screen as seen above, so figuring out how to clear your filter is not completely intuitive.  When one does scroll down, the other parts of the surrounding div get scrolled off-screen.

[image]

It seems to me that the filter drop-down should be able to extend beyond the surrounding div, or the div could have a minimum height that allowed the complete drop down to fit.  Afterall, when you complete a review queue (filtered or otherwise), there is nothing else to see on the screen below, so there is no reason for a drop down to be cut off and require scrolling.

Comment: This question should be posted at SE Meta. I posted a bug earlier today and my question immediately got feedback and the problem was fixed within a couple of hours.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, I thought about that but I wasn't sure what the standard procedure is with a little design bug like this.  I'll post on SE Meta shortly.

Comment: Check first that it hasn't been reported, and check to see if the flaw is still reproducible, there have been some "internal" fixes so maybe that menu has been sorted out. Good luck!

Comment: It's definitely still a flaw but I'm curious if it's just this site or all sites. I don't have reviews on any other site to find out >.<

Comment: @Mari-LouA - there is really no need to cross post bugs. We at Stack Exchange monitor all meta sites for bug reports.