# "Skip" skipped to new line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, suggested-edits, review

I just noticed this after reviewing an edit by clicking "[edit (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GP0H.png)":

> [image: skip is on its own line]

It should look something like this:

> [image: all buttons on same line]

I checked a couple of other sites, and this is the only site where the skip button is being forced onto another line.

Comment: Though TPTB state that issues, even global issues, may be reported in any Meta, in practice, problems which can only be addressed by SE and its employees (in this case devs or UX people) are better reported on [Meta.se]

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, but I guarantee that if I asked on MSE that the question would be closed as off topic there with the close reason "This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines defined in the help center. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated." TBTB watch all the metas, and they'll see this question.

Comment: @DanBron I've posted bugs here before and then posted them on Meta and was chastised for doing so.  [We at Stack Exchange monitor all meta sites for bug reports. – Oded](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/review-queue-filter-drop-down-cut-off-screen#comment45440_10882).  That said I think your point is valid, but also that once a bug is posted here it's probably best left here.

Comment: If TPTB programmed *Skip* to skip, it would be interesting to see what they might make *Improve Edit* do. :)

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Yes, I was not suggesting Laurel ask again on MSE, but rather that for issues like this, to get more and more immediate visibility, to ask on MSE in the first instance. Now that it's here, it should not be re-posted on MSE (unless this question is deleted first). I also suspect the issue is not specific to EL&U, so it would not have been closed as "site specific" on MSE. Others in other stacks may also be experiencing it, which is why MSE is a good place to post such issues.

Comment: Similar bug report on graphicdesign.SE: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/review-action-bar-alignment